# Options in select only selected if object is in two arrays

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to make a multiple select and show all nodes but only check the ones that are in 2 arrays.

I'm using Angular 8 and TypeScript for the front end.

```js
private mountSelect(nodesInRelation, lineApiKey) {
    console.log(nodesInRelation, lineApiKey);

    // if (nodesInRelation)

    let select = document.getElementById(lineApiKey);

     for (let node of this.allNodes) {
       for(let nodeInRelation of nodesInRelation) {
         if (node.name == nodeInRelation.name) {
           let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apikey, null, true);
           (select as HTMLSelectElement).add(newoption);
           break;
         } else {
                  let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apikey, null, false);
                  (select as HTMLSelectElement).add(newoption);
         }
       }

     }
M.updateTextFields();
    M.AutoInit();
  }
```

But I get duplicated entries.

```
    <tr *ngFor="let communityLine of communityLines">
      <td>{{communityLine.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.instrument.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.param.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.contextSource.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.sampleType.name}}</td>
      <td>{{communityLine.value}}</td>
      <td>
        <select multiple [id] ="communityLine.apiKey">
        </select>
      </td>
```

How can i do it efficiently?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would have to get bigger picture to get details right, but I would rewrite that code like this:

```
let nodeNames nodesInRelation.map(node => node.name);

let filteredNodes = this.allNodes.filter(function(node){
   return nodeNames.includes(node.name); // Use a polyfill for IE support
});
//I would set all nodes to false to prevent any weird issues
this.allNodes.forEach(node => {
           let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apikey, null, false);
           (select as HTMLSelectElement).add(newoption);
});
//then set only selected ones
filteredNodes.forEach(node => {
           let newoption = new Option(node.name, node.apikey, null, true);
           (select as HTMLSelectElement).add(newoption);
});
```

Comment: Finally I've used something like this. Also do you know how add an event to get the new value checked?